# AWS: Price Calculation with AWS Price List API using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

```
I want to calculate the total price for each instance types.
```

Step1) At first I am getting the EC2 Reservation Data:

```
    DescribeReservedInstancesRequest describeReservedInstancesRequest= new DescribeReservedInstancesRequest().withFilters(new LinkedList<Filter>());
    describeReservedInstancesRequest.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("state").withValues("active"));
    DescribeReservedInstancesResult describeReservedInstancesResult = ec2.describeReservedInstances(describeReservedInstancesRequest);

    describeReservedInstancesResult.getReservedInstances() gives me the reserve instance.
for(ReservedInstances reservedInstances : describeReservedInstancesResult.getReservedInstances()){
                EC2ResData ec2ResData = new EC2ResData();
                ec2ResData.setAvailabilityZone(reservedInstances.getAvailabilityZone());
                ec2ResData.setInstanceCount(reservedInstances.getInstanceCount());
                ec2ResData.setInstanceTenancy(reservedInstances.getInstanceTenancy());
                ec2ResData.setInstanceType(reservedInstances.getInstanceType());
                ec2ResData.setProductDescription(reservedInstances.getProductDescription());
                ec2ResData.setResInstanceId(reservedInstances.getReservedInstancesId());
                ec2ResData.setWindows(reservedInstances.getProductDescription().toLowerCase().indexOf("windows") != -1);
                ec2ResData.setInstanceName(getName(reservedInstances.getTags()));
                instanceTypeIndex.add(reservedInstances.getInstanceType());
                ec2ResData.setVPC(reservedInstances.getProductDescription().toLowerCase().indexOf("vpc") != -1);
                ec2ResDataList.add(ec2ResData);
            }
```

Step2) After that I am getting Ec2Data

```
DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstancesRequest = new 

    DescribeInstancesRequest().withFilters(new LinkedList<Filter>());
    describeInstancesRequest.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("instance-state-name").withValues("running"));
    List<Reservation> listReservation = ec2.describeInstances(describeInstancesRequest).getReservations();
    Set<Instance> instances = new HashSet<Instance>();
            for (Reservation reservation : listReservation) {
                instances.addAll(reservation.getInstances());
            }
            if (FormatManager.isFilled(instances)) {
                ec2DataList = new ArrayList<EC2Data>();
                for (Instance instance : instances) {
                    EC2Data ec2Data = new EC2Data();
                    ec2Data.setInstanceId(instance.getInstanceId());
                    ec2Data.setInstanceType(instance.getInstanceType());
                    ec2Data.setCurrentState(instance.getState().getName());
                    ec2Data.setAvailabilityZone(instance.getPlacement().getAvailabilityZone());
                    List<Tag> listTag = instance.getTags();
                    ec2Data.setInstanceName(getName(listTag));
                    if(FormatManager.isFilled(instance.getPlatform())){
                        ec2Data.setWindows(instance.getPlatform().toLowerCase().equals("windows"));
                    }
                    else{
                        ec2Data.setWindows(false);
                    }
                    instanceTypeIndex.add(instance.getInstanceType());
                    ec2Data.setVPC(FormatManager.isFilled(instance.getVpcId()));
                    ec2DataList.add(ec2Data);
                }
            }
```

Step3) After that I combine both reservation data and ec2 data (with unique combo of instance type, availability zone, windows, and vpc), where I have calculated reservation count, total number of running instances.
(http://awsresco.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/)

Now I need to calculate the price for those instances.

I have gone through the link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/.

Step4) With the use of https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/index.json I need to separate product information and pricing information.
I have used location product attributes to find the SKU that I needed to calculate the prices for.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/index.json");
    String responseString = FormatManager.fromInputStreamToString(fileInputStream,"UTF-8");
    org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = getJSONObject(responseString);
    org.json.simple.JSONObject products = getJSONObject("products",jsonObject);
    Set<Map.Entry<?,?>> entrySet = products.entrySet();

for (Map.Entry<?,?> entry : entrySet) {
                String sku = getJSONKey(entry);
                org.json.simple.JSONObject productItem = getJSONObject(sku,products);
                org.json.simple.JSONObject attributes = getJSONObject("attributes",productItem);
                String instanceType = getString("instanceType",attributes);
                String location = getString("location",attributes);
                String operatingSystem = getString("operatingSystem",attributes);
                String tenancy = getString("tenancy",attributes);
                String preInstalledSw = getString("preInstalledSw",attributes);
                String licenseModel = getString("licenseModel",attributes);


                //System.out.println("operatingSystem '"+operatingSystem+"' - preInstalledSw '"+preInstalledSw+"'");

                //System.out.println("location '"+location+"' - instanceType '"+instanceType+"'"+" - "+instanceTypeIndex);
                String targetLocation = "US West (Oregon)";
                if (targetLocation.equals(location)){
                    if (!skuIndexByInstanceType.containsKey(instanceType)){
                        skuSet.add(sku);
                        if (instanceTypeIndex.contains(instanceType)){
                            //We are interested on that instanceType
                            skuIndexByInstanceType.put(instanceType,entry);
                            skuInstanceTypeMap.put(sku, instanceType);
                            instanceTypeSKUMap.put(instanceType, sku);
                        }
                        else {
                            //We are not interested on that instance type
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Map.Entry<?,?> entryPrevious = skuIndexByInstanceType.get(instanceType);
                        throw new ServiceFatalException("instanceType '"+instanceType+"' is duplicated for location '"+location+"'. Here was entryPrevious '"+entryPrevious+"' and entry '"+entry+"'");
                    }
                }
                else {

                }
            }
```

Here I am confused as one SKU has many instance type. Which instance type I need to consider when calculating the price? How to differentiate the instance type in Step4 with that of Step1 and Step2.

Comment: Hi.. Were you able to find the answer of this ?